# Set the number of CPU cores

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am testing keras tensorflow under R, i would like to know how to specify the number of CPU cores. I only find tensorflow solutions under python without keras.

---

```
> library(keras)
> library(doParallel)
> cl <- makeCluster(2)
> registerDoParallel(cl)
> is_keras_available()
[1]TRUE
> foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% { is_keras_available()}
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "impossible to find the function "is_keras_available""
> parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `doParallel` library, you can detect the number of cores using  `detectCores()` function, and specify the number of cores to use with `registerDoParallel()` function.

Take a look to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Remember to include your libraries in the parallelization of your code through the `.export` parameter

```
foreach(i=1:3, .packages = c("keras")) %dopar% { is_keras_available()}
```

Comment: Hello, i tried to do this but i get a error, I edited my message to put the error.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the `is_keras_available()` function. I have edited the answer to load de library in each core.

Comment: i get this error: **Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : unable to find variable "keras"**.  I tried do to that: `foreach(i = 1:3, .export = c(library("keras"))) %dopar% { m <- keras_model_sequential()}`  i get this error: 
**Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  unable to find variable "doParallel"**

Comment: I am sorry, `.export` was to load objects, you need to put on `.packages`. Modified in the code.